How to find the Google Finance closing price average for the previous 20 months' end day as of the current date
I am using this formula but the date has been started from the first day of the month. so the average price was obtained wrongly.
AVERAGE(QUERY(GoogleFinance("GOOG", "CLOSE", EOMONTH(TODAY(), -21), TODAY(), "DAILY"), "select Col2 where day(Col1) = 1", 1))
Any idea how to get formula or modified this one.
Many thanks
but it returns:
"2023-10-31" "2023-10-01"
How can I obtain 09/30 instead of 10/01?
calculate the average of month end closed price for last 20 months in a single cell.

Can you add a table above showcasing us, ideally what are the 20 dates + values that the formula should be considering for the end average calculation?!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_bmvh9b8nMmz-0lCWmDMv8pEkqazartvilpYkYmUm8A/edit?usp=sharing
Please go through the link & open the G-sheet. allowed to make any alternation with the formula.
Thanks

Manually Enter the dates & closing values  from the 20 month period you ideally expect to see in calculating the final average. Right now your test sheet just showcases the above formula which you claim is not working!
